# Ajax success function not working after calling controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an ajax call from view to controller with some data passing to controller. Then the data is passed to the model and it is inserted in the db. It all works correctly. But i have some code in my ajax call success function, which is not working. I have no idea how to make it work.

My ajax call from view

```
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        dataType : "json",
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>att_controller/updt",
        data:{name:nam, age:ag, ids:id},
        success: function()
        {
            //code that i need to make work
        }
    })
```

my controller

```
public function updt(){
        $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
        $data['age']=$this->input->post('age');
        $data['id']=$this->input->post('ids');
        $this->load->model("Att_model");
        $this->Att_model->updt($data);


    }
```

my model

```
public function updt($data)
    {

        $this->load->database();
        $name=$data['name'];
        $age=$data['age'];
        $id=$data['id'];
        $this->db->query("update student set name='$name', age='$age' where id='$id'");
    }
```

need help to figure  this out.
i'm new to codeigniter

Comment: Do you mean the code in the success function isn't executing?  Like, can you put an alert in there and see the result?  If it's the code inside the function that you're having an issue with, why did you omit it from your example?  Or is success not being called at all?

Comment: I tried an alert. It doesn't work

Comment: In the same way you have a success function, add an error function.  Something like this should do, 
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to pass response in both the file controller and model. IN ajax call you defined `dataType:'JSON'` so in controller you need to convert your data into `json` format and pass it to view.

```
public function updt(){
        $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
        $data['age']=$this->input->post('age');
        $data['id']=$this->input->post('ids');
        $this->load->model("Att_model");
        $result['data'] = $this->Att_model->updt($data);
        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Also your model function will look like below.

```
public function updt($data)
{

        $this->load->database();
        $name=$data['name'];
        $age=$data['age'];
        $id=$data['id'];
        $query = $this->db->query("update student set name='$name', age='$age' where id='$id'");
        return $query->result();
}
```

Please check this and let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Thanx..It works..Now i know the reson. I found a better way. Just removed the dataType part from ajax.

Comment: @Anandhunadesh: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.